# Is there a way to filter out certain tags on the Steam store?

Tags: steam

There are some kinds of games that I really don't like, and it would be cool if I could somehow filter my Steam store view so that I don't see those games.  Thankfully, there are tags that describe these games, so I could theoretically avoid these tags in order to avoid these kinds of games.

Is there any way to filter the Steam Queue and Featured Games page to not show games that have certain tags?

As an example: I really don't like games with strong RTS elements.  Thus, it's not useful to me to have the Total War series show up in my feed.  Is there a way to force Steam to not show me games with the RTS tag in my queue?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to switch tags off, but from my experience, marking games I have no interest in as "Not Interested" results in a lot less of those types of games being advertised to me.

Comment: According to the tooltip on the 'Not Interested' button, that button doesn't change what gets recommended to you.  "This will not affect what other titles will be recommended for you."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### As of 6/23/2016, Yes.

1. Open Steam.
2. Click on your Discovery Queue.
3. Click "Customize your Queue".
4. Look under "Exclude products with these tags:"

From there, you can set specific tags to no longer show in your discovery queue.

Comment: `Visual Novel` - CHECK!

Comment: Unfortunately this only applies to discovery queue, not to the store as a whole. It would be nice to just filter out pornography everywhere, as it's completely filling up steam in certain categories.

Comment: You sir are a wonder. Now my discovery queue actually has good stuff in it, and itsn't filled with every 2 bit JRPG that comes out.

Answer (score 13):

Yes there is!
Following these steps through the menu's:

- Click on your account on the top right (next to your wallet)
- Go to 'Preferences'
- Scroll a bit down to 'Tags to Exclude'

Here you can add tags that will be ignored in discovery queue's, search results, suggestions, etc...

Comment: *that* is the current answer for this sort of thing, and should be the accepted one.

Comment: Sadly, it's current year and we *still* can only hide ten tags. What is this, 1985?

Answer (score 2):

No.

This function isn't implemented yet. As you can see [here](http://store.steampowered.com/tag), this function's missing right now. However, tags can be banned by Valve itself, but you can't block or ban tags yourself.

If you don't like to see a particular game, just click the "Not interested" button. It won't show up on your shop site anymore, still you can access it through search. Games you aren't interested in don't affect other games shown on Steam.

You can customize the bottom part of your start site. Nevertheless, there are just categories for customization. You can decide if you want so see

- Early Access Products.
- Games already in your account.
- Games.
- Software.
- Videos.

You can't modify the site any further, at least I don't know any way to do so.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct.